# Smooth animation CAGradientLayer with long duration

Tags: swift, animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

Created CAGradientLayer with a sharp color transition. Position of the color transition changes during the time with using CABasicAnimation.

Everything works, but if I use long duration, animation doesn't produce a smooth change.

Code of gradient creation

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75))
        path.addRect(CGRect(x: 75, y: 75, width: 50, height: 50))
        
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path
        
        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.mask = mask
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.orange.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0, 0]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient.frame = bounds
        
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
```

Animation code

```
func play() {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [0, 0]
        animation.toValue = [1, 1]
        animation.duration = 120
        animation.fillMode = .backwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
```

Demonstration of how the code works
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUvOo.gif

Are there any options to make the changes smooth with long animation duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a limitation of `CAGradientLayer`

You can check current progress of `CABasicAnimation` using layer `presentation()`.

And using `CADisplayLink` you can check updated value which presentation layer has for each frame, something like this:

```
    ...
    gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    let link = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(linkHandler))
    link.add(to: .main, forMode: .default)
    link.isPaused = false
}

@objc func linkHandler() {
    NSLog("\(gradient.presentation()?.locations)")
}
```

From this test you'll see that value gest updated totally fine, but `CAGradientLayer` rounds them to around `0.004`. Imagine that inside there's code like

```
locations = locations.map { round($0 * 250) / 250 }
```

I doubt there's anything you can do about that.

What you can do is use Metal do draw gradient by hand. It's a big and kind of scary topic, but drawing gradient isn't that hard. Check out [Rainbows](https://github.com/regexident/Rainbows), it's outdated you will have to update the syntax to the current one, but it should be possible

Comment: Thank you a lot.
I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to solve this problem.
Also special thanks for the recommendations of using Metal

Answer (score 0):

Your `draw` method is inserting a new gradient layer every time it is called. But this method will be called repeatedly, resulting in multiple layers being inserted. The only thing you should be doing in `draw` is stroking/filling paths, and in this case, you probably should not implement `draw` at all.

The insertion of layers does not belong in `draw`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information.
I'll create a gradient with using custom method.

Comment: Let us know whether this addresses the performance issue (as all those layers could easily slow it down).

Comment: I just tested it.
Animation seems smoother, but still not smooth enough

Comment: Is that on a device or simulator? Often animations are better on physical devices…

Comment: I tested it on simulator and also just tested on device iPhone 11. Got the same result (( https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc4Bb.gif